# Sharepoint Rest API - Create column error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx

i've currently got a requirement to create 3 columns in a list. Which i'm doing using the below function. This gets called 3 times and a different field name is passed each time.The guid that gets passed to the function is the id of the list I want to create the columns in.

```
 private async addCol(fieldName, guid): Promise<any> {
    const digestCache: IDigestCache = this.context.serviceScope.consume(DigestCache.serviceKey);
    digestCache.fetchDigest(this.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl).then((digest: string): void => {
      let obj = {};

      if (fieldName == "Full Address") {
        obj = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldText' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 2,'Title': 'Full Address'}";
      }
      if (fieldName == "Description") {
        obj = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldText' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 2,'Title': 'Description' }";
      }
      if (fieldName == "Location") {
        obj = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 31, 'Title': 'Location' }"
      }
      console.log("Post data: ");
      console.log(obj);

      $.post({
        url: this.context.pageContext.site.serverRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + guid + "')/fields",
        type: "POST",
        data: obj,
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": digest,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          //console.log("done");
          //console.log(data)
          console.log("added: " + fieldName);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          console.log(response.responseText);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

When the code runs, i get this error from the console:

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147023746, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The specified program requires a newer version of Windows. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007047E)"}}}
```

And only one column gets created. Is this something to do with Sharepoint taking its time to update the list?

Comment: can you check with  additional header `'odata-version':'3.0'` ? Modify it as `headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": digest,
    "odata-version":"3.0"
        },` and check ?

Comment: Looks like SPFx is using odata 4.0 which is causing some issue, we can try with odata 3.0 and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
 const digestCache: IDigestCache = this.context.serviceScope.consume(DigestCache.serviceKey);
digestCache.fetchDigest(this.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl).then((digest: string): void => {

  const h2 = new Headers();
  h2.append("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=full");
  h2.append("Content-type", "application/json;odata.metadata=full");

  const optUpdate1: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    headers: h2,
    body: `{ "@odata.type": "#SP.Field", "Title": "Location", "FieldTypeKind": 31, "Required": false, "EnforceUniqueValues": false, "StaticName": "Location"}`
  };

  const optUpdate2: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    headers: h2,
    body: `{ "@odata.type": "#SP.Field", "Title": "Full Address", "FieldTypeKind": 2, "Required": false, "EnforceUniqueValues": false, "StaticName": "Full Address"}`
  };

  // Options for Details column addition
  const optUpdate3: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    headers: h2,
    body: `{ "@odata.type": "#SP.Field", "Title": "Description", "FieldTypeKind": 2, "Required": false, "EnforceUniqueValues": false, "StaticName": "Description"}`
  };

  const myWebUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
  const spBatchCreationOptions: ISPHttpClientBatchCreationOptions = { webUrl: myWebUrl };
  const spBatch: SPHttpClientBatch = this.context.spHttpClient.beginBatch(spBatchCreationOptions);
  const addLocation: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> = spBatch.post(`${myWebUrl}/_api/web/lists(guid'${guid}')/Fields`, SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1, optUpdate1);
  const addPageUrlField: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> = spBatch.post(`${myWebUrl}/_api/web/lists(guid'${guid}')/Fields`, SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1, optUpdate2);
  const addDetailsField: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse> = spBatch.post(`${myWebUrl}/_api/web/lists(guid'${guid}')/Fields`, SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1, optUpdate3);
  let p: Promise<SPHttpClientResponse>[] = [addPageUrlField, addDetailsField, addLocation];

  console.log("Executing the batch, batches ;) ");
  spBatch.execute();

});
```

Changing __metadata to a @odata.type seemed to work along with batching. Enjoy :)